# Append a radio button with JQuery with label and have it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have appended a radio button with JQuery, but for some reason it won't let me select the button when clicking the label.  It works in HTML if you don't use jquery, so what am I missing:

```js
$(document).on("shown.bs.modal", "#signmein", function(e) {
  var html = '<input type="radio" name="colour" value="red" id="colour_red"><label for="colour_red">Red</label><br>';
  $('#modalload').append(html);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signmein">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal" id="signmein">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header ">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div>
                <label>The Field Label</label>
                <div class="input-append">
                  <div class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <div id="modalload"></div>
                    <br>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/yy3eAGjgGG

Comment: but it does match - check out the bootply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event handler somewhere that is preventing the default behavior of your label, I couldn't actually find it but stopping the propagation of the event fised it.

```js
$(document).on("click","#modalload label", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();    
});
$(document).on("shown.bs.modal","#signmein", function (e) {
   var html = '<input type="radio" name="colour" value="red" id="colour_red"><label onclick="/*event.stopPropagation();*/" for="colour_red">Red</label><br>';
    $('#modalload').html(html);       
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signmein">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal" id="signmein">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header ">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
     </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div>
          <label>The Field Label</label>
            <div class="input-append">
              <div class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons">
                <div id="modalload"></div>
                <br>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
      </div>         
     <div class="modal-footer">
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```